# Does Texas have standing to litigate against other States' election results?

Tags: us-constitution, jurisdiction, elections, standing

https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/states-blast-texas-bid-overturn-election-seditious-abuse/story?id=74656637

What standing is required (if any) for an entity (person, corporation, state, etc.) to litigate against the election results (be national or local)?

Please bear in mind I am NOT a lawyer.

Comment: According to Georgia, Wisconsin, Michigan, and Pennsylvania, it doesn't.  All four defendants raised "lack of standing" as a reason why the Texas litigation should be dismissed.

Comment: Have there been any class action lawsuits from citizens in the battleground states? IANAL, but it seems like they would have the appropriate standing. Would there be anything stopping the Texas AG from inspiring and assisting such an action?

Comment: Non-lawyer attempting plain-English:  to have standing, you have to have been **injured** in some way:  financial loss, damage to your possessions or business, injury, hindered in your activities, loss of the effect of YOUR vote, etc.  You have to have been directly involved, AND have a relevant legal right.  You cannot go to court and get a ruling to impose your will on someone else just because you dislike them or something they did or did not do; you cannot force someone to marry you, not marry someone else, or vote the way you want them to.

Comment: @Barmar There have been roughly6 50 lawsuits by voters and entities representing citizens and candidates in state and federal trial courts in individual states. The briefing of the parties recited many of them.

Comment: @ohwilleke I knew there were around 50 lawsuits, but I thought they were the ones brought by Giuliani on behalf of the Trump campaign. Are those citizen lawsuits in addition to them?

Comment: @Technophile A good example: Bob harms Charlie, but Charlie chooses not to sue Bob. Fred doesn't have standing to sue Bob in Charlie's place.

Comment: @Barmar There are quite an array of parties bringing lawsuits. I don't think that any are true "class action" lawsuits under Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 23 or the equivalent, because those are too slow to secure relief before they become moot. But, political parties and various non-profits and individual voters have also been parties. My count is not exact so defining it isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 41):

UPDATE: There is now a definitive answer.

[image]

#### There Is No Binding Judicial Precedent Adjudicating The Key Standing Issues Raised That Are Factually Squarely On Point

This is a novel argument.

To my knowledge, this is the first time that any state has ever sought judicial relief arising from another state's election administration, so it is a case of first impression not directly governed by a factually similar precedent.

Thus, rather than being governed by a precedent that resolved the exact standing question presented, we must result to more general principles.

Because it is a novel argument, it is impossible to be completely sure how it will be resolved.

#### General Considerations In Standing Law

**The General Rule**

Standing requirements require that there be a particularized actual injury to a legally recognized interest of the person suing.

Standing is a subcomponent of subject matter jurisdiction. Standing is one of the things that must be present for a court to have subject matter jurisdiction.

Standing is evaluated with reference to the merits. It exists if there is a recognized legal theory which, if proven, there has been a particularized injury to the person bringing the claim.

Most standing cases involve legal claims for relief that it is clear that someone validly has and the question is whether this particular person can assert them. But a minority of standing cases involve the question of whether there is a recognized legal claim of the type asserted at all.

No one has standing to assert a non-justiciable claim (i.e. a claim beyond the jurisdiction of all courts), or a claim for relief for which the courts do not legally recognize a remedy (e.g. a claim for not being chosen by a particular person to marry). As a result, standing can overlap with the argument that someone has failed to state a claim upon which relief can be granted.

**Generalized Grievances Don't Impart Standing**

Even if the law is perfectly clear that a law has been violated, that doesn't necessarily mean that anyone has standing to seek a remedy from a court for that violation of the law. To the extent that one has merely a [generalized grievance shared in common with everyone](https://scholarship.law.unc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=3677&context=nclr) (e.g. an interest in a correct outcome of a Presidential election, or a desire to have the government follow the law) that would not ordinarily suffice to establish standing.

Texas does not have an interest in the outcome of a Pennsylvania or Georgia Presidential election that is any different from the interest of a citizen of Texas or me, a citizen of Colorado. But citizens of a state other than the one in which the election was conducted who aren't candidates in that election clearly don't have standing to challenge the outcome of an election in another state.

If the Texas argument for standing is accepted, any voter in any state would have standing the contest the election results of every other state in every Presidential election (although not in the original jurisdiction of the U.S. Supreme Court).

#### The Argument For Standing Offered By Texas And Its Flaws

**The Texas Argument For Standing**

The Complaint argues for standing as follows in paragraph 18:

> In a presidential election, “the impact of the votes cast in each
> State is affected by the votes cast for the various candidates in
> other States.” Anderson, 460 U.S. at 795. The constitutional failures
> of Defendant States injure Plaintiff States because “‘the right of
> suffrage can be denied by a debasement or dilution of the weight of a
> citizen’s vote just as effectively as by wholly prohibiting the free
> exercise of the franchise.’” Bush v. Gore, 531 U.S. 98, 105 (2000)
> (quoting Reynolds v. Sims, 377 U. S. 533, 555 (1964)) (Bush II). In
> other words, Plaintiff State is acting to protect the interests of its
> respective citizens in the fair and constitutional conduct of
> elections used to appoint presidential electors.

**The Bush v. Gore Precedent Doesn't Establish Standing Here**

But *Bush v. Gore*, 531 U.S. 98, 105 (2000) (quoting *Reynolds v. Sims*, 377 U. S. 533, 555 (1964)) (Bush II) relied upon in the Complaint is not on point. Indeed, *Reynolds v. Sims* (which established a one man, one vote principle for state and local legislative redistricting) expressly recognized that the federal constitution would be illegal if a parallel system like the electoral college or U.S. Senate were enacted at the state level, but declined to hold that the 14th Amendment invalidated this portion of the U.S. Constitution (in part, because a valid constitutional amendments can't alter the equal representation of a U.S. state in the U.S. Senate without its consent).

*Bush v. Gore* likewise was an intrastate election dispute alleging that the equal protection rights of voters in one part of a state were abridged by the voters in another part of the state having different election rules applied to them in a lawsuit between two candidates in the race who clearly did have standing (although not original jurisdiction standing in the U.S. Supreme Court, which is limited with other exceptions inapplicable here, to lawsuits between two states).

**The Claim That Texas Has A Legally Cognizable And Justiciable Interest In The Overall Result Of A Presidential Election Is Unprecedented And Dubious**

The Complaint's assertion that in a presidential election, the impact of the votes cast in each State is affected by the votes cast for the various candidates in other States, citing *Anderson*, is also problematic.

First of all isn't technically true. The United States has 51 elections for Presidential electors, it doesn't have a "Presidential election" of ordinary voters. Perhaps an elector has standing to assert vote dilution, but an elector voting in that election, or a candidate, but they are not U.S. states and as a result, they can't bring lawsuits in the U.S. Supreme Court's constitutional original jurisdiction.

In the same way, Texas can't sue Florida alleging that a U.S. Senate or U.S. House election in Florida was conducted incorrectly, because every U.S. Senate or U.S. House election impacts which party has a majority in that house of Congress. Instead, the Constitution, recognizing that the courts offered no national judicial election remedy to people outside a state with a disputed election, created a legislative one by vesting resolution of disputed Congressional elections in Congress, rather than the Courts. Hundreds of disputed Congressional elections have been adjudicated that way.

Indeed, the only case of a genuinely disputed Presidential election outcome, [the election of 1876](https://history.house.gov/Historical-Highlights/1851-1900/The-electoral-vote-count-of-the-1876-presidential-election/#:%7E:text=On%20this%20date%2C%20a%20Joint,the%20185%20needed%20to%20win.), which is the closest precedent, is one in which Congress, rather than the Courts resolved the dispute regarding the overall Presidential election result based upon allegations of irregularities in a particular state.

One of the leading U.S. Supreme Court bar members [concurs with this analysis](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/supreme-court/5-glaring-problems-texas-bid-overturn-biden-s-win-u-n1250606):

> Texas has no legal right to claim that officials elsewhere didn't
> follow the rules set by their own legislatures. The United States
> doesn't have a national election for president. It has a series of
> state elections, and one state has no legal standing to challenge how
> another state conducts its elections any more than Texas could
> challenge how Georgia elects its senators, legal experts said.
>
> "This case is hopeless. Texas has no right to bring a lawsuit over
> election procedures in other states," said SCOTUSblog publisher Tom
> Goldstein, a Washington, D.C., lawyer who argues frequently before the
> court.

Second of all, it is irrelevant. *Anderson* didn't authorize one state to sue another state over its administration of an election. Even if the outcome of elections in other states have a *de facto* impact on other states, this doesn't mean that Texas has a legally cognizable interest in how another state selects its electors which is reserved to the legislature of the other state under the constitution.

There are no precedents for one state having a legally recognized interest in the outcome of another state's election. It did not participate in the election as a voter or an administrator of that election or as a candidate. It doesn't even cast a vote for President in any case, the electors that it elected do that.

The votes of the Texas electors are not diluted by the existence of electors in other states beyond the status quo expectation with no wrongdoing. Texas gets the same number of electoral votes relative to the total number of votes cast, regardless of who the electors of four other states cast their votes supporting. There is no allegation that another state got too many electoral votes.

In contrast, Texas might have standing to sue if it was allocated just 12 electoral votes, when, the census results showed that it was actually entitled to 38 electoral votes. Being denied the right to cast the full number of electoral votes that Texas gets to cast probably is an actual injury and does not hinge on how another state administers its election of its Presidential electors.

Links to the briefs filed by each of the four defendant states found [here](https://www.scotusblog.com/2020/12/states-tell-justices-to-deny-texas-request-to-overturn-2020-election/) further detail the standing analysis in addition to other arguments. For example, Michigan [summarizes its standing argument](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/22/22O155/163387/20201210145404465_22O155%20Texas%20MI%20BIO%2012-10.pdf) as follows:

> Texas lacks standing to bring its Electors Clause claim where its
> asserted injury is nothing more than a generalized grievance that the
> Clause was violated.

The [standing section in the Georgia brief](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/22/22O155/163383/20201210145849997_Georgia%20--%20Brief%20in%20Opposition.pdf) explains that:

> Texas lacks Article III standing to pursue its claims. Texas alleges
> two types of injuries—a direct injury to the State and a supposed
> injury to its Electors, whom Texas seeks to represent in a parens
> patriae capacity. Neither is cognizable.
>
> A. Texas argues that it has suffered a direct injury because “the
> States have a distinct interest in who is elected Vice President and
> thus who can cast the tiebreaking vote in the Senate.” Mot. for TRO
> 14–15 (emphasis in original); see also id. at 15 (arguing that a
> “Plaintiff State suffers an Article III injury when another State
> violates federal law to affect the outcome of a presidential
> election”). Under governing precedent, that is not an injury in fact.
> A State—like any plaintiff—has standing only if it alleges an injury
> that is actual or imminent, concrete, and particularized. See Spokeo,
> Inc. v. Robins, 136 S. Ct. 1540, 1547 (2016) (citing Lujan, 504 U.S.
> at 560); see also id. (injury in fact is the “[f]irst and foremost” of
> the standing elements) (quoting Steel Co. v. Citizens for Better
> Env’t, 523 U.S. 83, 103 (1998)). But Texas has no cognizable interest
> specific to Texas in how the Vice President  votes. Texas’s interest
> is in its own representation in the Senate; Georgia has not impaired
> that interest. Texas still has two Senators, and those Senators may
> represent Texas’s interests however they choose. Even by its own
> logic, Texas has suffered no injury.
>
> In any event, Texas’s speculation that the Vice President may one day
> cast a tie-breaking vote is not a cognizable injury. . . . Indeed, certain Vice Presidents—Mr.
> Biden, for example—never cast a tie-breaking vote during their tenure.
> Texas’s alleged injury is not the type of imminent, concrete, or
> particularized injury that Article III demands. See Clapper v. Amnesty
> Int’l USA, 568 U.S. 398, 410 (2013) (a “threatened injury must be
> certainly impending to constitute injury in fact” (quoting Whitmore v.
> Arkansas, 495 U.S. 149, 158 (1990))); id. (standing theory that
> “relies on a highly attenuated chain of possibilities[] does not
> satisfy the requirement that threatened injury must be certainly
> impending”).
>
> Texas’s alleged injury is also not cognizable because it is a
> generalized grievance—the kind of injury “that is ‘plainly
> undifferentiated and common to all members of the public.’” Lance v.
> Coffman, 549 U.S. 437, 440– 41 (2007) (quoting United States v.
> Richardson, 418 U.S. 166, 176–77 (1974)); id. (The only injury
> plaintiffs allege is that the law—specifically the Elections
> Clause—has not been followed. This injury is precisely the kind of
> undifferentiated, generalized grievance about the conduct of
> government that we have refused to countenance in the past.”); see
> also Gill v. Whitford, 138 S. Ct. 1916, 1923 (2018) (the alleged
> injury must be “distinct from a ‘generally available grievance about
> government’” (quoting Lance, 549 U.S. at 439)).
>
> The injuries that Texas alleges on behalf of its citizens are injuries
> that would be common to not only every citizen of Texas, but also
> every citizen of every state. Cf. Lance, 549 U.S. at 440 (“To have
> standing . . . a plaintiff must have more than a general interest
> common to all members of the public.” (quoting Ex parte Levitt, 302
> U.S. 633, 633 (1962))). And in all events, by Texas’s logic any State
> would have standing to pursue the alleged claims because every State
> purportedly “suffers an Article III injury when another State violates
> federal law to affect the outcome of a presidential election” (Mot.
> for TRO 15). So Texas’s injury is specific neither to its citizens nor
> to Texas as a State. An injury unique to no one is not an injury in
> fact.
>
> Texas cites no case supporting its assertion that it has suffered an
> injury in fact. Texas cites Massachusetts v. Envtl. Prot. Agency for
> the proposition that “states seeking to protect their sovereign
> interests are ‘entitled to special solicitude in our standing
> analysis’” (Mot. for TRO 15 (citing 549 U.S. 497, 520 (2007)), but
> Texas strips that language of its context. The Court there explained
> that Massachusetts was entitled to “special solicitude” in the
> standing analysis because a State has a quasi-sovereign interest in
> “preserv[ing] its sovereign territory” and because Congress had
> afforded “a concomitant procedural right to challenge the rejection of
> its rulemaking petition as  arbitrary and capricious.” Massachusetts,
> 549 U.S. at 519–20; see also Gov’t of Manitoba v. Bernhardt, 923 F.3d
> 173, 182 (D.C. Cir. 2019) (explaining context of the Court’s
> reasoning). Neither thing is true here. In any case, Massachusetts
> involved a State’s loss of coastal property from rising sea levels,
> which is nothing like Texas’s alleged injury (a speculative
> tie-breaking vote by the Vice President). Texas has not alleged a
> direct injury in fact.
>
> B. Nor does Texas have standing to raise claims for its electors in a
> parens patriae capacity (cf. Mot. for TRO 15). A State may sue parens
> patriae only if it proves that it has Article III standing (see, e.g.,
> Bernhardt, 923 F.3d at 178), which Texas hasn’t done. But even if it
> had, Texas would lack parens patriae standing because that concept
> applies only when a State seeks to vindicate the interests of more
> than a discrete and identifiable subset of its citizens (most often in
> the health and welfare contexts). See, e.g., Alfred L. Snapp & Son,
> Inc. v. Puerto Rico, 458 U.S. 592, 607 (1982) (“[M]ore must be alleged
> than injury to an identifiable group of individual residents . . .”);
> Pennsylvania v. New Jersey, 426 U.S. at 665 (a State may not sue
> parens patriae when it is “merely litigating as a volunteer the
> personal claims of its citizens”). Here, Texas purports to represent
> the interests of only thirty-eight people (its Electors).
>
> But Texas’s problems run even deeper. This Court has explained that
> “[o]ne helpful indication in determining whether an alleged injury to
> the health and welfare of its citizens suffices to give the State
> standing to sue as parens patriae is whether the injury is one that
> the State, if it could, would likely attempt to address through its
> sovereign lawmaking powers.” Alfred L. Snapp & Son, 458 U.S. at 607;
> see also Bernhardt, 923 F.3d at 178 (same). That is not the case here.
> Under our federalist system, Texas could never “address through its
> sovereign lawmaking powers” how another State elects its Electors.
> Texas lacks parens patriae standing.
>
> C. Texas also lacks standing because it asserts the rights of third
> parties. A plaintiff generally “cannot rest his claim to relief on the
> legal rights or interests of third parties” unless the plaintiff
> establishes (1) a “close” relationship with the third party and (2) a
> “hindrance” preventing the third party from asserting her own rights.
> Kowalski v. Tesmer, 543 U.S. 125, 129–30 (2004). Otherwise, the
> plaintiff fails to present a “particularized” injury. See Spokeo, 136
> S. Ct. at 1548; see also Warth v. Seldin, 422 U.S. 490, 502 (1975)
> (“Petitioners must allege and show that they personally have been
> injured, not that injury has been suffered by other, unidentified
> members of the class to which they belong and which they purport to
> represent.”). . . .
> The Eleventh Amendment bars Texas citizens from bringing such claims
> against Georgia in federal court, so Texas cannot circumvent that bar
> when asserting such individual rights in a parens patria capacity. See
> Georgia v. Pennsylvania R. Co., 324 U.S. 439, 465 (1945) (“By reason
> of the Eleventh Amendment the  derivative or attenuated injuries of
> that sort are not enough for standing. See, e.g., Hollingsworth v.
> Perry, 570 U.S. 693, 708 (2013) (“It is, however, a ‘fundamental
> restriction on our authority’ that ‘[i]n the ordinary course, a
> litigant must assert his or her own legal rights and interests, and
> cannot rest a claim to relief on the legal rights or interests of
> third parties.’” (quoting Powers v. Ohio, 499 U.S. 400, 410 (1991)).

The Pennsylvania opposition brief's section on standing [explains](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/22/22O155/163367/20201210142206254_Pennsylvania%20Opp%20to%20Bill%20of%20Complaint%20v.FINAL.pdf) that:

> Article III, Section 2 of the United States Constitution limits the
> jurisdiction of the federal courts to resolving “cases” and
> “controversies.” U.S. CONST. art. III, § 2; Raines v. Byrd, 521 U.S.
> 811, 818 (1997). That same jurisdictional limitation applies to
> actions sought to be commenced in the Court’s original jurisdiction.
> Maryland v. Louisiana, 451 U.S. 725, 735-36 (1981). To establish
> standing, the demanding party must establish a “triad of injury in
> fact, causation, and redressability.” Steel Co. v. Citizens for a
> Better Environment, 523 U.S. 83, 103 (1998). More specifically, that
> the plaintiff has suffered injury to a legally protected interest,
> which injury is “fairly traceable to the challenged action and
> redressable by a favorable ruling.” AIRC, 576 U.S. at 800; see also
> Maryland, 451 U.S. at 736.
>
> This Court has “always insisted on strict compliance with this
> jurisdictional standing requirement.” Raines, 521 U.S. at 819. For
> invocation of the Court’s original jurisdiction, this burden is even
> greater: “[t]he threatened invasion of rights must be of serious
> magnitude and it must be established by clear and convincing
> evidence.” People of the State of N.Y. v. New Jersey, 256 U.S. 296,
> 309 (1921). Texas fails to carry this heavy burden.
>
> First, Texas cannot establish it suffered an injury in fact. An injury
> in fact requires a plaintiff to show the “invasion of a legally
> protected interest”; that the injury is both “concrete and
> particularized”; and that the injury is “actual or imminent, not
> conjectural or hypothetical.” Spokeo, Inc. v. Robins, 136 S. Ct. 1540,
> 1548 (2016). According to Texas, the alleged violations of
> Pennsylvania’s Election Code undermined the authority granted to the
> Pennsylvania General Assembly under the Electors Clause.8 Motion at 3,
> 10-11, 13-15. But as the text of the Electors Clause itself makes
> clear, the injury caused by the alleged usurpation of the General
> Assembly’s constitutional authority belongs to that institution. AIRC,
> 576 U.S. at 800 (legislature claimed that it was stripped of its
> responsibility for redistricting vested in it by the Elections
> Clause). The State of Texas is not the Pennsylvania General Assembly.
> See Virginia House of Delegates v. Bethune-Hill, __ U.S. __, 139 S.Ct.
> 1945, 1953 (2019) (noting the “mismatch between the body seeking to
> litigate [the Virginia House of Delegates] and the body to which the
> relevant constitutional provision allegedly assigned exclusive
> redistricting authority [the General Assembly]”).
>
> Second, Texas’s claimed injury is not fairly traceable to a violation
> of the Electors Clause. As discussed above, each of Texas’s
> allegations of violations of Pennsylvania law has been rejected by
> state and federal courts.
>
> Third, Texas fares no better in relying on parens patriae for
> standing. It is settled law that “a State has standing to sue only
> when its sovereign or quasi-sovereign interests are implicated and it
> is not merely litigating as a volunteer the personal claims of its
> citizens.” Pennsylvania, 426 U.S. at 665. The state, thus, must
> “articulate an interest apart from the interests of particular private
> parties.” Alfred L. Snapp & Son, Inc. v. Puerto Rico, ex rel., Baez,
> 458 U.S. 592, 607 (1982).
>
> In other words, “the State must be more than a nominal party.” Ibid.
> That, however, is exactly what Texas is here. Texas seeks to “assert
> parens patriae standing for [its] citizens who are Presidential
> Electors.” Motion at 15. Even if, as Texas claims, the presidential
> electors its citizens have selected suffered a purported injury akin
> to the personal injury allegedly sustained by the 20-legislator bloc
> in Coleman v. Miller, 307 U.S. 433, 438 (1939), which they did not,
> that does not somehow metastasize into a claim by the state rather
> than those presidential electors. The 20-person bloc of legislatures
> in Coleman sued in their own right without the involvement of the
> State of Kansas. Ibid. Texas has no sovereign or quasi-sovereign
> interest at stake. It is a nominal party, at best.
>
> 8 In its motion, Texas disclaims a “voting-rights injury as a State”
> based on either the Equal Protection or Due Process Clauses. Motion at
> 14. Rather, Texas claims that its legally protected interest arises from “the structure of the Constitution” creating a federalist system
> of government. Ibid. As discussed infra, to the extent Texas relies on
> the Equal Protection and Due Process Clauses, those “Clauses protect
> people, not States.” Pennsylvania, 426 U.S. at 665.

Wisconsin's [standing argument](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/22/22O155/163393/20201210150111653_Brief.pdf)s are as follows:

> At a minimum, to invoke this Court’s original jurisdiction, Texas must
> demonstrate that it has “suffered a wrong through the action of the
> other State.” Maryland v. Louisiana, 451 U.S. 725, 735–36 (1981). But
> Texas is unable to allege that Wisconsin itself did anything to
> directly injure Texas’s sovereign interests. Instead, Texas advances a
> far more attenuated theory of injury—that the other States’ supposed
> violations of their elections laws “debased the votes of citizens” in
> Texas. Mot. for P/I at 3. This speculative logic is not nearly enough
> to carry Texas’s burden to prove, by “clear and convincing evidence,”
> a “threatened invasion of [its] rights” “of serious magnitude,” New
> York, 256 U.S. at 309. Indeed, Texas’s allegations fall far short of
> what would be required by Article III in any federal case—that is, a
> showing that a plaintiff has “(1) suffered an injury in fact, (2) that
> is fairly traceable to the challenged conduct of the defendant[s], and
> (3) that is likely to be redressed by a favorable judicial decision.”
> Spokeo, Inc. v. Robins, 136 S. Ct. 1540, 1547 (2016).
>
> It is well settled under the Court’s original jurisdiction cases that
> “a State has standing to sue only when its sovereign or
> quasi-sovereign interests are implicated and it is not merely
> litigating as a volunteer the personal claims of its citizens.”
> Pennsylvania v. New Jersey, 426 U.S. 660, 665 (1976).
>
> Apart from attempting to rely on the “personal claims of its citizens”
> as electors or voters, Texas struggles to identify any traditional
> sovereign injury to support its claim under the Electors Clause.
> Instead, Texas proposes that this Court recognize a new “form of
> voting-rights injury”—an injury premised on the denial of “‘equal
> suffrage in the Senate’” somehow caused by the election of the Vice
> President. Mot. for Prelim. Inj. at 14 (quoting U.S.Const. art. V, cl.
> 3).
>
> Texas makes no freestanding constitutional claim to this effect. In
> any event, this argument makes no sense. Texas does not (and cannot)
> argue that it now has fewer Senators than any other state. By
> definition, therefore, it maintains “equal suffrage in the Senate.”
>
> Texas’s attempt to garner standing for its claims under the Equal
> Protection and Due Process Clauses fares no better. These “Clauses
> protect people, not States.” Pennsylvania, 426 U.S. at 665.
>
> If Texas’s theory of injury were accepted, it would be too easy to
> reframe virtually any election or voting rights dispute as implicating
> injuries to a States and thereby invoke this Court’s original
> jurisdiction. New York or California could sue Texas or Alabama in
> this Court over their felon-disenfranchisement policies. . . . .
>
> This case does not satisfy the direct-injury requirement. Texas
> speculates that Wisconsin’s facilitation of mail-in voting during the
> pandemic may have increased the likelihood that third parties would
> engage in instances of voter fraud in Wisconsin. Texas does not offer
> a shred of evidence that any such fraud occurred. And Texas does not
> allege that Wisconsin directed or authorized any individual to engage
> in voter fraud. Nor would any such allegation be plausible.
>
> In any event, this Court long made clear that its original
> jurisdiction does not extend to “political disputes between states
> arising out of [the alleged] maladministration of state laws by
> officials to the injury of citizens of another state.” Stephen M.
> Shapiro, et al, Supreme Court Practice 10-6 (11th ed. 2019); see
> Louisiana v. Texas, 176 U.S. 1, 15 (1900)) (“Jurisdiction over
> controversies of that sort does not embrace the determination of
> political questions, and, where no controversy exists between states,
> it is not for this Court to restrain the governor of a state in the
> discharge of his executive functions in a matter lawfully confided to
> his discretion and judgment.”). It is hard to imagine a case that more
> clearly runs afoul of that principle than a dispute over the outcome
> of the presidential election, premised on the alleged
> maladministration of state election law.

#### The Existence Of A Legally Cognizable Interest Needs To Be Evaluated In The Context Of The U.S. Constitution As A Whole

The question of first impression concerning whether a state has a legally cognizable interest in the administration of an election in another state needs to be evaluated in the context of the U.S. Constitution as a whole.

The Constitution says a fair amount about election administration and disputed elections that in context disfavors the notion that one state has a legally cognizable interest in how another state administers an election administration.

All federal elections in the United States (outside the District of Columbia) are administered by the states and by the local governments and agencies created by the states. State election laws must conform to federal requirements, and candidates participating in elections or voters in that state have standing in many cases to litigate whether those state and federal laws were conformed to by state election administrators. Each election of electors is separate and prior to 1852, Presidential elections weren't even held on the same day even though the Congress had the authority to mandate a single Presidential election date.

The process of determining a total outcome of the election by aggregating state electoral college votes is vested in Congress by the constitution, not in the judicial branch, and so there can be no legally cognizable interest in this non-justiciable issue. Therefore, not only does Texas lack standing to bring this suit on the theory asserted that Texas is injured by an aggregation of electoral votes including votes allegedly made by improperly certified electors. No one has standing to do so in any court of law.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the work to write the question.  However, the paragraph that starts with "Bush v Gore" is very difficult to follow.  Please, make it more clear.  The paragraph that starts with "there are no precedents" seems to contradict 18 of the complaint (as quoted in David Siegel's answer). All paragraphs after that one seem to be about the merit of the complaint rather than standing.  I have to downvote because this is more ranty than informative.  Again, my apologies because you clearly put work into it.

Comment: The idea that courts have no voice in the outcome of the election is a statement about jurisdiction rather than standing.  The novelty of the case may arise from TX attempting to put forward a theory asserting standing as one of the merits of the case, but if that's part of what you are trying to say, then that should be made more clear, too.

Comment: Standing is a subcomponent of subject matter jurisdiction. Standing is one of the things that must be present for a court to have subject matter jurisdiction. Standing is evaluated with reference to the merits. It exists if there is a recognized legal theory which, if proven, there has been a particularized injury to the person bringing the claim. No one has standing to assert a non-justiciable claim (i.e. a claim beyond the jurisdiction of all courts).

Comment: I understand that standing is a sub-component of jurisdiction.  But it doesn't work in reverse.  Not every issue of jurisdiction (eg. justiciability) is an issue of standing.  It maybe relevant to the complaint.  But that doesn't, in itself, make it relevant to this (more narrow) question.

Comment: Since standing hinges on the merits, whether there is a legally cognizable theory of relief can present an issue of standing. It rarely presents that way in standing cases, however, because most standing cases involve well established claims on the legal merits for someone and the question is whether they belong to the Plaintiff, not whether there is a claim for what is asserted at all.

Comment: Ok, the 2nd paragraph, in the new edit, makes it a very good answer.  I upvoted now.  On the face of it, standing being a component of jurisdiction does not seem like it would make other matters of jurisdiction relevant to standing.  But the fact that (as a result) there is lack of ability to provide relief (which makes it a matter of standing) is a good explanation.

Comment: @grovkin Thanks for your input allowing me to improve my answer.

Comment: BTW, DOJ would have standing to sue states in SCOTUS on the 14th amendment grounds, would it not?  So a state can't, for example, disenfranchise all black voters, through legislature or otherwise.  So the issue of equal protection is justiciable.

Comment: @grovkin In practice, the DOJ sues state election officials in U.S. District Court seeking injunctive relief under the Voter Rights Act, rather than suing in SCOTUS, even though it could do otherwise.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this reasoning could be applied in other cases if it were to be successful.  For example, if we assume this case if valid, could California potentially sue Florida for purging large numbers of people from the voter rolls without sufficient effort to determine if they were actually invalid or merely had the same name as a dead person.

Comment: @EriucNolan Most of the defending states make that argument.

Comment: @EricNolan on the subject of purging voter rolls, I'm betting the likelihood of you having the exact same legal name and birth date and living in the exact same precinct as a person who just died that year is pretty slim to nil, it can happen.  Those issues can and should be addressed by due diligence of each registered voter to ensure that their voting standing is valid.  I do, every two years, about 3-6 months prior to any elections.  Even if the person shows and theres a registration irregularity, and showing proper identification, I believe they can vote provisionally.

Comment: @enorl76 That's weird principle to take. My voting status should not change until I move. Nobody should have to do "due diligence" to make sure they are still registered if they haven't moved.

Comment: @AzorAhai I agree. enorl76's practice seems more like an abundance of caution rather than *due* diligence.

Comment: @grovkin Yeah, there's no reason to purge voter rolls except suppression.

Comment: @ohwilleke, you might want to include the primary point of that document in the image as text, and add a link if possible.

Comment: Even being a balloted candidate is not enough to achieve standing to sue over a state's election results. Jill Stein had no standing to challenge Michigan's 2016 results since there was no chance a recount would give Jill Stein the victory. (the Greens were hoping a recount would show a Democratic victory, a far less bad outcome for the Greens than a Republican victory.)

Comment: For those who are wondering about the statement from Alito & Thomas in the decision:  SCOTUS has historically taken the position that they have a choice whether or not to hear cases that come before them under original jurisdiction.  Alito & Thomas have argued (here and in previous cases) that SCOTUS does not have this discretion, and that all such cases must be heard by the Supreme Court.

Answer (score 6):

The complaint asserts thst:

> 17. This Court has original and exclusive
>     jurisdiction over this action because it is a
>     “controvers[y] between two or more States” under
>     Article III, § 2, cl. 2 of the U.S. Constitution and 28
>     U.S.C. § 1251(a) (2018).

> 18. In a presidential election, “the impact of
>     the votes cast in each State is affected by the votes
>     cast for the various candidates in other States.”
>     *Anderson,* 460 U.S. at 795. The constitutional failures
>     of Defendant States injure Plaintiff States because
>     “‘the right of suffrage can be denied by a debasement
>     or dilution of the weight of a citizen’s vote just as effectively as by wholly prohibiting the free exercise of
>     the franchise.’” *Bush v. Gore*, 531 U.S. 98, 105 (2000)
>     (quoting *Reynolds v. Sims*, 377 U. S. 533, 555 (1964))
>     (Bush II). In other words, Plaintiff State is acting to
>     protect the interests of its respective citizens in the
>     fair and constitutional conduct of elections used to
>     appoint presidential electors.

The suit goes on to say

> Moreover, redressability likely
> would undermine a suit against a single state officer
> or State because no one State’s electoral votes will
> make a difference in the election outcome. This action
> against multiple State defendants is the only
> adequate remedy for Plaintiff States, and this Court
> is the only court that can accommodate such a suit.

This seems to assert that improper procedure would injure Texas by causing an incorrect outcome, and therefore asserts standing. I don't know of a case closely on point.

### Update

The issue has now been settled. The Court has rejected the Bill of Complaint for lack of standing. See the answer by @ohwilleke for a full quote of the court order dismissing the case.

Comment: "the right of suffrage can be denied by a debasement or dilution of the weight of a citizen’s vote" ... dilution already happens, to the extent that 29 million Texans elect 38 EC voters (763000 pop per EC vote), while the same population in ND elect 3 EC votes. And yet the party that primarily benefits from this, want to draw attention to it...

Comment: @BrianDrummond North Dakota does not have the same population as Texas.

Comment: @phoog : oops, I can see how you got there, but to be more explicit; I meant approx the "same population in ND" as the 763000 Texans who only get one EC vote.